# pyqtgraph: When I click on a PlotItem how do I know which item has been clicked

Tags: pyqtgraph

I don't konw if my method is the right method, but it works.

```
class PltItem(pg.PlotItem):

    pltClicked = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(PltItem, self).__init__(parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        super(PltItem, self).mousePressEvent(ev)
        self.pltClicked.emit()
```

the in the main window i use

```
for i, plt in enumerate(self.plts):
    self.connect(plt, SIGNAL("pltClicked()"), partial(self.selectplot, i))

def selectplot(self, i):
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is a good one. Another solution is to connect to the GraphicsScene.sigMouseClicked signal and use [QGraphicsScene.items()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsscene.html#items-2) to determine whether a PlotItem (or any other item) was under the click.