# How to plot the horizontal distance between 2 points on an image with PyQtGraph

Tags: python, qt, pyside2, pyqtgraph

I'd like to plot the horizontal distance between 2 points on an image with PyQtGraph, but I can't draw it.
I think it a way of doing this would be to use 3 instances of LineSegmentROI and make them look connected as one right arc, because they already have many features that would be great for this idea.
Like being draggable, which could be very useful to measure a different distance by simply dragging a side.
The problem are the handles, that can't be removed, or even hidden.
Has anyone done something like this?

### [image: example.png]

```
# import the necessary packages
from pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.ImageItem import ImageItem
from pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.LinearRegionItem import LinearRegionItem
import requests
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui


image = cv2.imread('example.png') # Change if you save the image with a different name
image = cv2.rotate(image, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

## Create window with GraphicsView widget
w = pg.GraphicsView()
w.show()
w.resize(image.shape[0], image.shape[1]) # Depending on the picture you may need to resize
w.setWindowTitle('Test')

view = pg.ViewBox()
view.setLimits(xMin=-image.shape[0]*0.05, xMax=image.shape[0]*1.05,
               minXRange=100, maxXRange=2000,
               yMin=-image.shape[1]*0.05, yMax=image.shape[1]*1.05,
               minYRange=100, maxYRange=2000)
w.setCentralItem(view)

## lock the aspect ratio
view.setAspectLocked(True)

## Add image item
item = ImageItem(image)
view.addItem(item)

# Add Line
line = pg.QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem(200, -100, 400, -100, view)
line.setPen(pg.mkPen(color=(255, 0, 0), width=10))
view.addItem(line)

def mouseClicked(evt):
    pos = evt[0]
    print(pos)

proxyClicked = pg.SignalProxy(w.scene().sigMouseClicked, rateLimit=60, slot=mouseClicked)


## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up borrowing `RectItem` from [drawing a rectangle in pyqtgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60012070/drawing-a-rectangle-in-pyqtgraph/60012800) and using its code for `LineItem`.
With three `LineItem`s I draw the distance meter between the 2 points.
I still have to add some signals and slots to handle resizing, but I'm working on it.
However the core of the solution is here and I'll follow up with my improvements

```py
# import the necessary packages
from PySide2.QtCore import QLineF, Qt, Signal, Slot, QObject, QPointF, QRectF, QSizeF
from PySide2.QtGui import QRegion
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QGraphicsItem, QLabel, QWidget
from pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.ImageItem import ImageItem
from pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.LinearRegionItem import LinearRegionItem
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.ViewBox.ViewBox import ViewBox


image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
image = cv2.rotate(image, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

## Create window with GraphicsView widget
w = pg.GraphicsView()
w.show()
w.setWindowTitle('Test')

view = pg.ViewBox()
view.setLimits(xMin=0, xMax=image.shape[0],
               minXRange=100, maxXRange=2000,
               yMin=0, yMax=image.shape[1],
               minYRange=100, maxYRange=2000)
w.setCentralItem(view)

## lock the aspect ratio
view.setAspectLocked(True)

## Add image item
item = ImageItem(image)
view.addItem(item)


class LineItem(pg.UIGraphicsItem):

    moved = Signal(QPointF)

    def __init__(self, line, extend=0, horizontal=False, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initialPos = QLineF(line)
        self._line = line
        self.extend = extend
        self.horizontal = horizontal

        self._extendLine()

        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        self._generate_picture()

        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)

    @property
    def line(self):
        return self._line

    def _extendLine(self):
        if (self.extend != 0 and not self.horizontal):
            self._line.setP1( QPointF(self._line.x1(), self._line.y1() - abs(self.extend)) )
        # if (self.horizontal):
        #     self.extend = 0
        # self._line.setP1( QPointF(self._line.x1(), self._line.y1() - abs(self.extend)) )

    def _generate_picture(self):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        painter.setPen(pg.mkPen(color="y", width=2))
        painter.drawLine(self.line)
        painter.end()

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        painter.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)

    def boundingRect(self):
        lineShape = self.picture.boundingRect()
        lineShape.adjust(-10, -10, 10, 10)
        return QtCore.QRectF(lineShape)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange:
            # value is the new position.
            if self.horizontal:
                if value.x() != 0:
                    value = QPointF(0, value.y())
            else:
                if value.y() != 0:
                    value = QPointF(value.x(), 0)
            self.moved.emit(value)
        return pg.UIGraphicsItem.itemChange(self, change, value)


class Distance(QObject):
    def __init__(self, A: QPointF, B: QPointF, view: ViewBox, parent: QWidget=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        if A.x() > B.x():
            self.A, self.B = B, A
        self.distance = abs(B.x() - A.x())

        print(self.A)
        print(self.B)

        extend = 50
        top = max(self.A.y(), self.B.y()) + 200
        self.left = LineItem(QtCore.QLineF(self.A.x(), self.A.y(), self.A.x(), top), extend)
        self.right = LineItem(QtCore.QLineF(self.B.x(), self.B.y(), self.B.x(), top), extend)
        self.top = LineItem(QtCore.QLineF(self.A.x(), top, self.B.x(), top), horizontal=True)

        self.top.setPos(0, 0)

        self.left.moved.connect(self.onLeftSegmentMoved)
        self.right.moved.connect(self.onRightSegmentMoved)
        self.top.moved.connect(self.onTopSegmentMoved)

        self.label = pg.TextItem(str(round(self.distance, 2)), color=(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00), anchor=(1, 1))
        # self.label.setParentItem(self.top)
        self.label.setPos(self.A.x()+self.distance/2, top + 5)

        view.addItem(self.label)
        view.addItem(self.left)
        view.addItem(self.top)
        view.addItem(self.right)

    @Slot(QPointF)
    def onLeftSegmentMoved(self, delta: QPointF):
        topLeft = self.top.initialPos.p1()
        newX = topLeft.x() + delta.x()
        newTopLeft = QPointF(newX, topLeft.y())
        self.top.line.setP1(newTopLeft)
        self.top._generate_picture()

        pos = self.label.pos()
        self.distance = abs(self.top.line.x2() - self.top.line.x1())
        self.label.setPos(newX + (self.top.line.x2() - self.top.line.x1())/2, pos.y())
        self.label.setText(str(round(self.distance, 2)))

    @Slot(QPointF)
    def onTopSegmentMoved(self, delta: QPointF):
        leftTop = self.top.initialPos.p1()
        newY = leftTop.y() + delta.y()
        newLeftTop = QPointF(leftTop.x(), newY)
        self.left.line.setP2(newLeftTop)
        self.left._generate_picture()

        rightTop = self.top.initialPos.p2()
        newY = rightTop.y() + delta.y()
        newRightTop = QPointF(rightTop.x(), newY)
        self.right.line.setP2(newRightTop)
        self.right._generate_picture()

        pos = self.label.pos()
        self.label.setPos(pos.x(), newY)

    @Slot(QPointF)
    def onRightSegmentMoved(self, delta: QPointF):
        topRight = self.top.initialPos.p2()
        newX = topRight.x() + delta.x()
        newTopRight = QPointF(newX, topRight.y())
        self.top.line.setP2(newTopRight)
        self.top._generate_picture()

        pos = self.label.pos()
        self.distance = abs(self.top.line.x2() - self.top.line.x1())
        self.label.setPos(newX - (self.top.line.x2() - self.top.line.x1())/2, pos.y())
        self.label.setText(str(round(self.distance, 2)))


distance = Distance(QPointF(925, 425), QPointF(138, 500), view)
```

Comment: This was all I needed. Thank you so much!