# Find plot-item under cursor

Tags: python, pyqt, mouseevent, pyside, pyqtgraph

I have created a small code that gives me back what window that was under the cursor when the mouse was pressed. However, I am also generating multiple 
subplots, by calling `addPlot`. Is there a way to return what graph (subplot) 
was under the cursor when pressing the mouse?

```
from PySide.QtGui import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QFileDialog)
import pyqtgraph as pg


class MyGraphWindow(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):
    def __init__(self, mainwindow):
        super(MyGraphWindow, self).__init__()
        self.mainwindow = mainwindow


    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        log.debug("%r", ev)
        self.mainwindow.window_activated(self)
        return super(MyGraphWindow, self).mousePressEvent(ev)
```

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428251/pyqtgraph-when-i-click-on-a-plotitem-how-do-i-know-which-item-has-been-clicked